# tools/config.py --kernel release

Tags: spresense

spresense SDKです。
[examples/camera](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/camera) を確認していますが、エラーで進めません。

OS: Windows 10
msys64のmsysターミナルで実行しました。

```
$ tools/config.py --kernel release
WARNING:root:-k option is deprecated. Ignored.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/config.py", line 412, in <module>
    dest = Defconfig(base, manager)
  File "tools/config.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.path = manager.get_fullpath(name)
  File "tools/config.py", line 111, in get_fullpath
    raise RuntimeError('Config "%s" not found' % name)
RuntimeError: Config "release" not found
```

config.pyのオプション `--kernel` が無視されたようですが、サイトを探しても解決方法が見つけられませんでした。どなたかご存じでしたらご指導願います。

Comment: `tools/config.py --kernel --list` を実行するとどうなりますか？ / "`--kernel` は deprecated なので無視" の部分はあくまで警告であり、エラーになっているのは 指定した "release" が見つからない、の方に問題がありそうです。

Answer (score 0):

古いドキュメントを参照しているのかもしれません。

公式サイトの手順が参考になると思います。

[Spresense SDKスタートガイド(CLI版) サンプルアプリケーション "Hello, World!" の実行手順](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3_hello_world_%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86)
[Spresense SDKチュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html)

`--kernel` は旧SDKバージョンでのオプションのようです。